# Pycharm SqlAlchemy autocomplete not working

Tags: python, autocomplete, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and Pycharm, but PyCharm can't see methods of SQLAlchemy for autocomplete function.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.sqlite3'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, unique=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For example, if I want call SQLAlchemy method of User class i must type full method name manually User.query.filter_by(username='peter').first()
[Autocomplete example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP5QT.jpg)

**How to make autocomplete work for SQLAlchemy?**

1) Yes, project was reloaded several times 
2) Yes, right interpreter in File | settings | Project 
3) Yes, PyCharm is not in Power Save Mode 
4) Yes, I have Professional edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm SQLAlchemy autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793590/pycharm-sqlalchemy-autocomplete)

Answer (score 16):

PyCharm (or any other IDE) can't find most methods (`query()`, `add()`, `commit()` etc) as they are not defined in `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` class. SQLAlchemy methods are added to `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` objects dynamically during initialization. You can find this initialization function in [flask_sqlalchemy module](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L66):

```
def _include_sqlalchemy(obj):
    for module in sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy.orm:
        for key in module.__all__:
            if not hasattr(obj, key):
                setattr(obj, key, getattr(module, key))
```

Just for the testing: you can type `from sqlalchemy.orm import Query`. I think PyCharm will find it's objects just fine.

I can't suggest any solution, maybe someone else here know about possibility of dynamically added attributes autocompletion.

Answer (score 14):

```py
class User(db.Model):
    query: db.Query # Type hint here
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, unique=True)
```

adding type hint `query: db.Query`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just use like this

```
class Aa(db.Model):
    query: db.Query = db.session.query_property()
    __tablename__ = 'aa'
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    uuid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
```

[image]

then we got

```
print(Aa.query.first()) # <Aa 1>
```