# How to define a ContextManager Protocol

Tags: python, type-hinting, contextmanager

I am trying to use type hinting to specify the API to follow when implementing a connector class (to a broker, in this case).

I want to specify that such class(es) should be context manager(s)

How do I do that?

Let me reword it more clearly: **how can I define the `Broker` class so that it indicates that its concrete implementations, e.g. the `Rabbit` class, must be context managers?**

Is there a practical way? Do I have to specify `__enter__` and `__exit__` and just inherit from `Protocol`?

Is it enough to inherit from `ContextManager`?

By the way, should I use `@runtime` or `@runtime_checkable`?  (My VScode linter seems to have problems finding those in `typing`. I am using python 3 7.5)

I know how to do it with ABC's, but I would like to learn how to do it with protocol definitions (which I have used fine already, but they weren't context managers).

I cannot make out how to use the `ContextManager` type. So far I haven't been able to find good examples from the official docs.

At present I came up with

```
from typing import Protocol, ContextManager, runtime, Dict, List


@runtime
class Broker(ContextManager):
    """
    Basic interface to a broker.
    It must be a context manager
    """

    def publish(self, data: str) -> None:
        """
        Publish data to the topic/queue
        """
        ...

    def subscribe(self) -> None:
        """
        Subscribe to the topic/queue passed to constructor
        """
        ...

    def read(self) -> str:
        """
        Read data from the topic/queue
        """
        ...
```

and the implementation is

```
@implements(Broker)
class Rabbit:
    def __init__(self,
            url: str,
            queue: str = 'default'):
        """
        url: where to connect, i.e. where the broker is
        queue: the topic queue, one only
        """
        # self.url = url
        self.queue = queue
        self.params = pika.URLParameters(url)
        self.params.socket_timeout = 5

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(self.params) # Connect to CloudAMQP
        self.channel = self.connection.channel() # start a channel
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue) # Declare a queue
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.connection.close()

    def publish(self, data: str):
        pass  # TBD

    def subscribe(self):
        pass  # TBD

    def read(self):
        pass  # TBD
```

Note: the `implements` decorator works fine (it comes form a previous project), it checks the class is a subclass of the given protocol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hints and context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733699/python-type-hints-and-context-managers)

Comment: @wpercy thank you. I had come across that QA already, and the answers do not show how to declare the abstract class (protocol), they show functions decorated with contextlib, which I know how to use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer -- your `Rabbit` implementation is actually fine as-is. Just add some type hints to indicate that `__enter__` returns an instance of itself and that `__exit__` returns `None`. The types of the `__exit__` params don't actually matter too much.

---

Longer answer:

Whenever I'm not sure what exactly some type is/what some protocol is, it's often helpful to check TypeShed, the collection of type hints for the standard library (and a few 3rd party libraries).

For example, [here is the definition of typing.ContextManager](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L384). I've copied it below here:

```
from types import TracebackType

# ...snip...

_T_co = TypeVar('_T_co', covariant=True)  # Any type covariant containers.

# ...snip...

@runtime_checkable
class ContextManager(Protocol[_T_co]):
    def __enter__(self) -> _T_co: ...
    def __exit__(self, __exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
                 __exc_value: Optional[BaseException],
                 __traceback: Optional[TracebackType]) -> Optional[bool]: ...
```

From reading this, we know a few things:

1. This type is a Protocol, which means any type that happens to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` following the given signatures above would be a valid subtype of `typing.ContextManager` without needing to explicitly inherit it.
2. This type is runtime checkable, which means doing `isinstance(my_manager, ContextManager)` also works, if you want to do that for whatever reason.
3. The parameter names of `__exit__` are all prefixed with two underscores. This is a convention type checkers use to indicate those arguments are positional only: using keyword arguments on `__exit__` won't type check. Practically speaking, that means you can name your own `__exit__` parameters whatever you'd like while still being in compliance with the protocol.

So, putting it together, here is the smallest possible implementation of a ContextManager that still type checks:

```
from typing import ContextManager, Type, Generic, TypeVar

class MyManager:
    def __enter__(self) -> str:
        return "hello"

    def __exit__(self, *args: object) -> None:
        return None

def foo(manager: ContextManager[str]) -> None:
    with manager as x:
        print(x)        # Prints "hello"
        reveal_type(x)  # Revealed type is 'str'

# Type checks!
foo(MyManager())



def bar(manager: ContextManager[int]) -> None: ...

# Does not type check, since MyManager's `__enter__` doesn't return an int
bar(MyManager())
```

One nice little trick is that we can actually get away with a pretty lazy `__exit__` signature, if we're not actually planning on using the params. After all, if `__exit__` will accept basically anything, there's no type safety issue.

(More formally, PEP 484 compliant type checkers will respect that functions are contravariant with respect to their parameter types).

But of course, you can specify the full types if you want. For example, to take your `Rabbit` implementation:

```
# So I don't have to use string forward references
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional, Type
from types import TracebackType

# ...snip...

@implements(Broker)
class Rabbit:
    def __init__(self,
            url: str,
            queue: str = 'default'):
        """
        url: where to connect, i.e. where the broker is
        queue: the topic queue, one only
        """
        # self.url = url
        self.queue = queue
        self.params = pika.URLParameters(url)
        self.params.socket_timeout = 5

    def __enter__(self) -> Rabbit:
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params) # Connect to CloudAMQP
        self.channel = self.connection.channel() # start a channel
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue) # Declare a queue
        return self

    def __exit__(self,
                 exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
                 exc_value: Optional[BaseException],
                 traceback: Optional[TracebackType],
                 ) -> Optional[bool]:
        self.connection.close()

    def publish(self, data: str):
        pass  # TBD

    def subscribe(self):
        pass  # TBD

    def read(self):
        pass  # TBD
```

---

To answer the new edited-in questions:

> How can I define the Broker class so that it indicates that its concrete implementations, e.g. the Rabbit class, must be context managers?
>
> Is there a practical way? Do I have to specify **enter** and **exit** and just inherit from Protocol?
>
> Is it enough to inherit from ContextManager?

There are two ways:

1. Redefine the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions, copying the original definitions from ContextManager.
2. Make Broker subclass *both* ContextManager and Protocol.

If you subclass only ContextManager, all you are doing is making Broker just inherit whatever methods happen to have a default implementation in ContextManager, more or less.

[PEP 544: Protocols and structural typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) goes into more details about this. The [mypy docs on Protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) have a more user-friendly version of this. For example, see the section on [defining subprotocols and subclassing protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols).

> By the way, should I use @runtime or @runtime_checkable? (My VScode linter seems to have problems finding those in typing. I am using python 3 7.5)

It should be [`runtime_checkable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable).

That said, both Protocol and runtime_checkable were actually added to Python in version 3.8, which is probably why your linter is unhappy.

If you want to use both in older versions of Python, you'll need to pip install [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/), the official backport for typing types.

Once this is installed, you can do `from typing_extensions import Protocol, runtime_checkable`.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt and info. But the focus of my question is the `Broker` class. Is ok as it is? Please see my edit

Comment: @Pynchia -- I added a new section to the bottom of my post with answers to your new questions.

Comment: Ok, much cleaner now. Thank you,  I will experiment

Comment: Thanks @Michael0x2a! A small update, as of today at [`1459adc`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/commit/1459adc), [`typing.ContextManager`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/1459adc/stdlib/typing.pyi#L124) is re-exporting [`contextlib.AbstractContextManager`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/1459adc/stdlib/contextlib.pyi#L40-L46).

Comment: @Michael0x2a Great anwser! 
Where does the `@implements` decorator you are using in your example come from?