# mypy complains '"object" has no attribute "__enter__"' for compound `with` expression

Tags: python, mypy

I'd like to conditionally use `with` with an `io.TextIOWrapper` either directly from `open()` or from one yielded by another context manager.  For example:

```py
import contextlib
import io
import typing


def condition() -> bool:
    return True


@contextlib.contextmanager
def foo() -> typing.Generator[io.TextIOWrapper, None, None]:
    with open("README.md", "rb") as f:
        yield io.TextIOWrapper(f)


with foo() if condition() else open("README.md") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end="")
```

The above code runs without error, but running `mypy` on it reports:

> ```
> foo.py:16: error: "object" has no attribute "__enter__"
> foo.py:16: error: "object" has no attribute "__exit__"
> ```

`mypy` is satisfied if I use either subexpression in isolation (i.e., `with foo() as f:`), but the combination confuses it.  I presume that there's some subtle difference in the typehints for `foo()`'s and `open()`'s return values that causes their common, inferred supertype to be `object`.  Using `typing.cast` quells the complaint:

```py
with (typing.cast(io.TextIOWrapper, foo()) if condition() else
      open("README.md")) as f:
```

Is there something else that I should be doing instead (e.g. by tweaking the typehint for the return value of `foo` or maybe by implementing `foo` in some other way)?

Comment: [Is this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49736916/5168011)?

Comment: @Guy I've read that already, and I don't think it is (or maybe I'm too dense to understand which part would help my case).  I'm already using a `Generator` annotation for the return type; I don't see how using `Iterator` would be any better. `typeshed` indicates that [`open` is hinted to return an `io.TextIOWrapper`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/9645dae9250d397a2ae81c7cc7db9b2d0d64180a/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1413) already (for at least one overload, anyway).

Comment: [Simple workaround](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=e2be52139988879b79baecbbf5b6e38b). I suppose the problem is that `io.TextIOWrapper` is a self-returning context manager, so `mypy` gets confused.You probably should report this as `mypy` issue.

Comment: I should have checked the mypy issue tracker first.  This looks like https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5512.